# False Positives in Google Analytics

Tags: apache, google-analytics, ip-geolocation

I run a very niche website.

There is absolutely no way it gets organic traffic; its url is not .com, it's also not easy to type or remember, it's more like sub.sub.domain.xyz/some/path/. domain.xyz shows a blank page.

The website contains data that I share with my colleagues and only 3 people know about it, all of them live in the US but do a lot of travel (of course, those 3 people may have shared it to others as well).

I track their behavior by a custom set of scripts that parse the raw HTTP server logs. I also make use of AWStats, which is essentially the same thing. And, finally, Google Analytics.

The typical activity on my site is something like 2-3 visits/week. Usually I can pinpoint which person is using it because I know where they live (they are from different cities among the world).

Recently, Google Analytics showed me a (relatively speaking) huge spike in traffic from the UK that lasted for two days. Funny thing is that, when looking at my HTTP log, I see no IP's that I could geolocate to the UK. **Actually, the only two IPs I see logged around those days are one from a colleague in the US and my own one.**

Does Google Analytics reports data that is not completely true? Particularly, false positives?

Or else, what could be happening here?

Comment: Its possible to upload data into your GA property from a foreign domain. Have you checked the hostname dimension? Go to all pages report and select "host" as a primary/secondary dimension. What shows up? If there is some foreign domain then somebody just wanted to upload some data into your property, for no meaningful reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spike might be the result of spam traffic. Make sure to filter your site for your hostname only.